# perl regexp:How to use named captures in string replacement?

Tags: regex, perl

I have to replace  a string with another in many files. The string is special prefix we use with all internal jarnames.

For example following line with expresslaunch

```
 <encrypt key="${encrypt.key}" file="${expresshome}/lib/expresstools.jar"/>
```

becomes

```
 <encrypt key="${encrypt.key}" file="${expresshome}/lib/turbotools.jar"/>
```

The following substitution works.

```
$line =~ s/express(?<JARNAME>[a-zA-Z_]+?\.jar)/turbo\1/g;
```

I was trying to use named captures (new in perl 5.1). The following code, however,  did not work.

```
$line =~ s/express(?<JARNAME>[a-zA-Z_]+?\.jar)/turbo$+{JARNAME}/g;
```

What is the catch? Does the name capture works only with pattern matching?

Comment: The example in your post should work fine. (Although you really shouldn't be munging XML with regexes if you can avoid it.) Also if you're using numbered captures you should use `$1` and not `\1`.

Comment: Thanks. The file is an ant build file(hundreds of them). The patterns are line specific, so hope this is going to work :)

Comment: You can also just delete your question if you find out there's really no question there. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a named capture in a regex, you access its value with the `%+` variable. The feature works as you expect.

Your code works just fine. This is one of the reasons I advocate always writing a complete and runnable example program to go with your question. Once you strip out everything else going on in your big program, you might find that the part you isolated works just as you expect and is not the problem.